# Do validators duplicate business logic?

Tags: asp.net, dry, validation

I know it's possible to use validators to check data input in the presentation layer of an application (e.g. regex, required fields etc.), and to show a message and/or required marker icon. Data validation generally belongs in the business layer. How do I avoid having to maintain two sets of validations on data I am collecting?

**EDIT:** I know that presentation validation is good, and that it informs the user, and that it's not infallible. The fact remains, does it not, that I am checking effectively the same thing in two places ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and no.

It depends on the architecture of your application. We'll assume that you're building an n-tier application, since the vast majority of applications these days tend to follow that model.

Validation in the user interface is designed to provide immediate feedback to the end-user of the system to prevent functionality in the lower tiers from ever executing in the first place with invalid inputs. For example, you wouldn't even want to try to contact the Active Directory server without both a user name and a password to attempt authentication. Validation at this point saves you processing time involved in instantiating an object, setting it up, and making an unnecessary round trip to the server to learn something that you could easily tell through simple data inspection.

Validation in your class libraries is another story. Here, you're validating *business rules*. While it can be argued that validation in the user interface and validation in the class libraries are the same, I would tend to disagree. Business rule validation tends to be far more complex. Your rules in this case may be more nuanced, and may detect things that cannot be gleaned through the user interface. For example, you may enforce a rule that states that the user may execute a method only after all of a class's properties have been properly initialized, and only if the user is a member of a specific user group. Or, you may specify that an object may be modified only if it has not been modified within the last twenty-four hours. Or, you may simply specify that a string value cannot be null or empty.

In my mind, however, properly designed software uses a common mechanism to enforce DRY (if possible) from both the UI and the class library. In most cases, it is possible. (In many cases, the code is so trivial, it's not worth it.)

Comment: So, in effect, e.g. an empty string check is not a business rule, it's a validation rule. A business rule should be more concerned with checking it makes sense to do an action, not that the data is valid to peform an action on?

Comment: An empty string is both a UI check and a business rule validation. If the client has JavaScript disabled then the client side validation will never fire. That does not mean you will never check for empty string since your business rules should be handling this case in the rules engine. 

As MikeHofer said, UI validation is to provide immediate feedback to the client.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think client-side (presentation layer) validation is actual, useful validation; rather, it simply notifies the user of any errors the server-side (business layer) validation will find.  I think of it as a user interface component rather than an actual validation utility, and as such, I don't think having both violates DRY.

EDIT: Yes, you are doing the same action, but for entirely different reasons.  If your only goal is strict adherence to DRY, then you do not want to do both.  However, by doing both, while you may be performing the same action, the results of that action are used for different purposes (actually validating the information vs. notifying the user of a problem) , and therefore, performing the same action twice actually results in useful information each time.

Comment: I agree; validation in those locations may perform the same task, but for different purposes; in the presentation layer it is for increased usability, in the data layer to ensure consistent data.

Comment: The whole purpose of client side validation is to filter out the bad data so the business layer do not have to deal with null/empty strings or invalid data.

Comment: @azamsharp - that's a bit idealistic I think.  In the case of the web, the client side really has no relation to what a user can actually submit, it's so easy to change a posted request.  You should never trust the data that is submitted to your business layer when dealing with the web.

Comment: I am not implying that we should not have a business level validation. Business validation is the most important validation in the application. But we should also provide the UI validation (input validation). If there is no input validation then we are sending un-filtered data back to the business validation framework again and again. It is good to filter the data at input level. Of course, we cannot filter 100% of input data!

Comment: @azamsharp I think you're misconstruing the point of UI validation. The point is not to avoid sending back unfiltered data to the business validation framework - that fact that we can't do this robustly means that the business validation framework must be robust against unfiltered data anyway, so there's nothing to be gained on that front from UI validation.

In a web or similar context UI validation is useful solely because of the better experience it creates for the user. We can apply it sooner than the business validations, and having errors caught sooner is a nicer experience.

Answer (score 0):

I think having good validations at application layer allows multiple benefits.
1. Facilitates unit testing
2. You can add multiple clients without worrying about data consistency.

UI validation can be used as tool to provide quick response times to the end users.

Answer (score 0):

Each validation layer serves a different purpose. The user interface validation is used to discard the bad input. The business logic validation is used to perform the validation based on business rules.

For UI validation you can use RequiredFieldValidators and other validators available in the ASP.NET framework. For business validation you can create a validation engine that validates the object. This can be accomplished by using the custom attributes.

Here is an article which explains how to create a validation framework using custom attributes:

http://highoncoding.com/Articles/424_Creating_a_Domain_Object_Validation_Framework.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Following up on a comment from Fredrik Mörk as an answer, because I don't think the other answers are quite right, and it's important for the question.

At least in a context where the presentation validation can be bypassed, the presentation validations and business validations are doing completely different things.

The business validations protect the application. The presentation validations protect the time of the user, and that's all. They're just another tool to assist the user in producing valid inputs, assuming that the user is acting in good faith. Presentation validations should not be used to protect the business validations from having to do extra work because they can't be relied upon, so you're really just wasting effort if you try to do that.

Because of this, your business validations and presentation validations *can* look extremely different. For business validations, depending on the complexity of your application / scope of what you're validating at any given time, it may well be reasonable to expect them to cover all cases, and guarantee that invalid input is impossible.

But presentation validations are a moving target, because user experience is a moving target. You can almost always improve user experience beyond what you already have, so it's a question of diminishing returns and how much effort you want to invest.

So in answer to your question, if you want good presentation validation, you may well end up duplicating certain aspects of business logic - and you may well end up doing more than that. But you are not doing the same thing twice. You've done two things - protected your application from bad-faith actors, and provided assistance to good-faith actors to use your system more easily. In contexts where the presentation layer cannot be relied upon, there is no way to reduce this down so that you only perform a task like "only a number please" once.

It's a matter of perspective. You can think of this as "I'm checking that the input is a number twice", or you can think "I've guaranteed that I'm not getting a number, *and* I've made sure the user realises as early as possible that they're only supposed to enter a number". That's two things, not one, and I'd strongly recommend that mental approach. It'll help keep the purpose of your two different kinds of validations in mind, which should make your validations better.